# Updating input value attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I currently calculate a random value with jQuery and save it to a variable.

I want this variable to be the value of:

```
<input type="text" class="mastery_num" name="mastery_num" id="mastery_num" value="VALUE_FROM_JQUERY"></input>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val):

```
var your_variable = doMyCalculation();
$("#mastery_num").val(your_variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mastery_num").val(your_saved_variable);
```

`.val()` is  jQuery's equivalent of the plain JavaScript `.value` property. `.val()` either returns or sets the value depending on whether you supply a value to it.

Plain JavaScript version, for future viewers:

```
document.getElementById("mastery_num").value = your_saved_variable;
```